# adding errorbars to individual points in faceted plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a faceted plot from a dataframe showing how one variable changes as a function of other variable.  Each variable has an error associated with it.  Here's a subset of the data I have; an ID column, the variables (SiO2 to FeO) and the errors associated with the variables (*_2stdev):

```
df<-structure(list(ID = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("P466-an1", "P466-an2", "P468-an1", "P468-an2", "P469-an1", "P470-an1", "P471-an1", "P472-an1", "P473-an1", "P474-an1", "P475-an1", "P475-an2", "P476-an1", "P476-an2", "P477-an1", "P478-an1", "P479-an1", "P480-an1"), class = "factor"), 
           SiO2 = c(54.5147, 56.2223, 52.8499, 52.0293, 53.4221, 52.9802), 
           TiO2 = c(0.5928, 0.5792, 0.5771, 1.1373, 1.0962, 1.1535), 
           Al2O3 = c(17.5404, 18.1921, 19.4737, 15.7752, 16.455, 16.4117), 
           FeO = c(6.2115, 5.8676, 5.4874, 4.5952, 4.4242, 4.109), 
           SiO2_2stdev = c(1.5232, 2.3578, 0.6374, 1.3331, 0.6535, 0.6977), 
           TiO2_2stdev = c(0.0638, 0.0637, 0.0357, 0.1024, 0.0422, 0.0282), 
           Al2O3_2stdev = c(0.4519, 0.4572, 0.2044, 0.6378, 0.6546, 0.0624), 
           FeO_2stdev = c(0.426, 0.3973, 0.1145, 0.1992, 0.1106, 0.0427)), 
          .Names = c("ID", "SiO2", "TiO2", "Al2O3", "FeO", "SiO2_2stdev", "TiO2_2stdev", "Al2O3_2stdev", "FeO_2stdev"), 
          row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the following code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

m.df<-melt(df, id=c('ID','FeO'))

p<-ggplot(subset(m.df, variable %in% c('SiO2','TiO2','Al2O3')),aes(x=value, y=FeO))+
   geom_point()+
   facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol=1, scales="free_x")+
   theme_bw()

p
```

I get this plot:

[image: plot with no errorbars]

I would like to add the errorbars (vertical and horizontal) to this, but I don't know how to do this on a faceted plot.

Using `geom_errorbar` and `geom_errorbarh`, I've been able to plot these for individual plots from the unmelted dataframe.  I suppose I could make all the plots with a loop, but I don't know how to add the errorbars with this method.  Further, I'd like to see all the plots at once.

Thanks for reading this and any help is greatly appreciated!
-R

**edit**
As per *aosmith*'s comment, I've added `FeO_2stdev` to the ID variables in `melt`.  I'm now  able to produce a plot with the correc vertical errorbars.  So now I have trouble understanding how I can get `geom_errorbarh` to plot the correct errorbars on for each plot.

Below is the updated code I'm using, with the resulting plot.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

m.df<-melt(df, id=c('ID','FeO', 'FeO_2stdev'))
m.df$y.min<-m.df$FeO-m.df$FeO_2stdev
m.df$y.max<-m.df$FeO+m.df$FeO_2stdev

p<-ggplot(subset(m.df, variable %in% c('SiO2','TiO2','Al2O3')), aes(x=value, y=FeO))+
   geom_point()+
   facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol=1, scales="free_x")+
   theme_bw()+
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y.min, ymax=y.max))

p
```

[image: plot with vertical errorbars]

Comment: Are you trying to add error bars based on `FeO_2stdev`?  If so, keep this variable as one of your id variables in `melt` so you can use it in `geom_errorbar`.  If not, can you clarify what you'd use to calculate the error bars?

Comment: Ah, yes!  I've now done this and can get the FeO errorbars to plot.  Now, my question is how to plot the appropriate horizontal errorbars on each plot.   I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a dataset with one column of values and one column of 2 standard deviations will help with the horizontal error bars.  This is essentially a data manipulation problem.  There are many ways to achieve such a thing.  I'm using *tidyr* with *dplyr*.

For example, if you start with `m.df` immediately after melting, you could

1. Make a new variable to represent whether the row represents 2 standard deviations or the value using `separate` and then `mutate` with `if_else`.
2. `spread` the dataset back into a wide format, with one column for the values and one for the 2 standard deviations.  You could also use `dcast` from *reshape2* if you are already familiar with it.

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

```
m.df %>%
    separate(variable, c("variable", "metric")) %>%
    mutate(metric = if_else(is.na(metric), "value", metric)) %>%
    spread(metric, value)

         ID    FeO FeO_2stdev variable 2stdev   value
1  P466-an1 4.5952     0.1992    Al2O3 0.6378 15.7752
2  P466-an1 4.5952     0.1992     SiO2 1.3331 52.0293
3  P466-an1 4.5952     0.1992     TiO2 0.1024  1.1373
4  P466-an2 4.4242     0.1106    Al2O3 0.6546 16.4550
5  P466-an2 4.4242     0.1106     SiO2 0.6535 53.4221
...
```

Here's the whole process using `gather` from *tidyr* instead of `melt` for the same results:

```
df2 = df %>%
    gather(key, value, -ID, -contains("FeO")) %>%
    separate(key, c("variable", "metric")) %>%
    mutate(metric = if_else(is.na(metric), "value", metric)) %>%
    spread(metric, value)
```

Now the horizontal error bars can be added to your plot using `value` and `2stdev`.  Note that the column name `2stdev` isn't syntactically correct so I use backticks around the variable name.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=value, y=FeO))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol=1, scales="free_x")+
    theme_bw() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = FeO - FeO_2stdev, ymax = FeO + FeO_2stdev)) +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = value - `2stdev`, xmax = value + `2stdev`))
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent!  Thank you.  A one question: Why is the backtick required around `2stdev` but not `value` in `geom_errorbarh`?

Comment: In R, names that start with numbers aren't syntactically valid so `2stdev` has to be wrapping back-ticks but `value` does not.  The [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html) for `make.names` contains some helpful info about syntactically valid names.